# Requested replacement mode is not supported for this request : Google Play billing

Tags: android, google-play, payment, google-play-console

Need help, I am getting this error when **I have already purchased one subscription plan and purchasing same plan again before expiry of previous one**. Using google play billing with **deferred** proration mode for this.[image]

Developer error
Description - "Requested replacement mode is not supported for this request"

used standard code for this.

String offerToken = productDetails
.getSubscriptionOfferDetails(selectedOfferIndex)
.getOfferToken();

BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
.setProductDetailsParamsList(
ImmuableList.of(
ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
// fetched via queryProductDetailsAsync
.setProductDetails(productDetails)
// offerToken can be found in
// ProductDetails=>SubscriptionOfferDetails
.setOfferToken(offerToken)
.build()))
.setSubscriptionUpdateParams(
SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
// purchaseToken can be found in Purchase#getPurchaseToken
.setOldSkuPurchaseToken("old_purchase_token")
.setReplaceSkusProrationMode(ProrationMode.DEFERRED)
.build())
.build();

BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);

Moreover it works fine when I use proration mode like IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_FULL_PRICE and
IMMEDIATE_WITHOUT_PRORATION but not with DEFERRED.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any luck for solution?

Comment: I resolved this issue In my case it was dues to India does not accept subscription amounts of more then 5000. Just verify it in case anyone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this one?

```html
setSubscriptionReplacementMode(BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.ReplacementMode.CHARGE_FULL_PRICE)
```